# Toggling the direction of line flow animation in draw.io

Tags: draw.io

I am building out a data flow diagram in draw.io. I have been able to setup some toggle 'buttons' that utilizes the custom links / action functionality to toggle on/off the flow animation of lines in a particular data flow path. However, there are instances when the line in a path flows in the opposite direction of another flow path using the same line. When I'm editing the diagram, I can easily 'fix' / update the direction by using the 'reverse' button under the Arrange tab for the line. However, that button seems to do some XML updating for the drawing (swapping source and target values) instead of changing some property or style value(s).

I've looked at the custom link tool that I found linked on a draw.io page (https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/link.html) and it seems to suggest that I can only update / change line property and style values, which doesn't include changing / swapping source and target information.

Is there a way to use the action links to toggle the direction of a line's flow animation? Currently, the only way I have found to 'toggle' the direction of a line is to duplicate every line in my diagram so that there are both directions, and then toggle which line is shown. Although this technically solves the problem, it makes managing the diagram significantly more complex, error prone and likely to display things incorrectly.

Not sure if this information helps / matters. I am using the draw.io plugin / app for Confluence, version number: 12.1.6

Also, I do not want to create a separate page for each data flow. I'd like to have just one page with display toggles so that, if I ever have to update objects within the diagram, I only have to update a single page, instead of having to propagate the change across many pages.